# Flutter - Suddenly got this error ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN

Tags: exception, flutter, firebase-authentication

App was working perfectly fine, But suddenly it's stop working.

I have a firebase phone auth in my app. I have added one test number in fireabse, But once I enter test number and test OTP and hit submit button I got this exception.

```
PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN, This user's credential isn't valid for this project. This can happen if the user's token has been tampered with, or if the user isn't for the project associated with this API key., null)
```

I am not able to understand what's the problem and how to fix this.

Comment: Phasing the same problem, have you find the solution?

Comment: Automatically solved, may be some internal glitches from firebase servers

Answer (score 1):

make sure you haven't changed the project path, i solved it moving the project to original path.

Comment: This is not a complete answer explaining the cause with reason. This should be as comment.

Comment: Please explain in detail , folder name you are telling ? What is the path ?